# How to update the las row of the table with Django OMR queryset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I´m trying to make an update with the django OMR but I don´t know the id. Only I konw that I want to update the last record. The other columns are not useful because the data is similar except for the date column(could be an aoption but the django OMR don´t recognized my query)

My actual query:

```
Tracking = TrackEExercises.filter(
                            exe_date = (fecha + delta).replace(microsecond=0)
                            ).update(data_tracking = dataT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the last record based on the id:

```
last_record = TrackEExercises.objects.filter(exe_date=your_exe_date).order_by('-id')[0]
# Update
last_record.data_tracking = dataT
last_record.save()
```

You can also use `.last()` and `.first()`:

```
TrackEExercises.objects.filter(exe_date=your_exe_date).order_by('-id').first()
TrackEExercises.objects.filter(exe_date=your_exe_date).order_by('id').last()
```

which returns the same record.

You can use `order_by()` to order the results based on any other field like a date:

```
TrackEExercises.objects.order_by('-exe_date')
```